# Brahmic conscript with European style

Tags: writing-systems

The scripts of South Asia (i.e. the Indian subcontinent), e.g. Devanagari, and Southeast Asia, e.g. Thai, are almost all derived from the Brahmic script. They show gradual visual relationships and most of them are structurally similar. They are syllabaries with non-default vowels being denoted by diacritics and consonant clusters often forming complex ligatures.

Is there any constructed variant of this family of scripts that intentionally uses shapes found in the major European scripts (Roman, Cyrillic and Greek)? Preferably, it would be based upon the stems and loops of lowercase Roman letters. I think it’s impossible to achieve in a readable way, but maybe there is even a [mimicry or "faux Latin" font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Mimicry_typefaces) for one of the existing scripts (e.g. Burmese or Malayalam) that would qualify.

PS: I have attached some roman letters in red to similar looking glyphs in the picture below. The imagined conscript would have a consistent set of letters and diacritics that looked much like roman ones.

[image: Brahmic-derived scripts in current use, set in Noto showing a sample phrase in Sanskrit]

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean? A Brahmic inspired script which has borrowed forms from the Latin script? Latin consonants used as an abugida with diacritics instead of the Lain vowels?

Comment: The former. A Brahmic script that strongly reminds one of the Roman script. If it was built closely matching the Malayalam script, for instance, the letters ട ധ ന would look (almost) the same as _s w m_.

Comment: Font designer's already have done this, seee e.g. Samarkan on this page: https://www.free-fonts.com/search?q=Devanagari%20Script%20Style

Comment: @jknappen Samarkan is a Roman faux Devanagari font. I rather mean a Brahmic faux Roman font.

Comment: Can you create a picture of a hypothetical example of the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: Oh, you're actually after a font, not a script?

Comment: No, I’m not really looking for a font, but since the South-Asian scripts are so closely related, one could make a faux Roman font at least for some of them.

Comment: You've really gotta explain what you want more clearly. Font requests aren't on topic here, so if that's not what you really want, please explain better.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I have now added an image that hopefully makes it a bit clearer. As you can see, none of the related scripts can easily be faked with roman letters, hence a simple mimicry font will not do, a complete conscript is required.

Comment: I'm assuming that your intent with the image is to reproduce the same set of syllables in all of the listed scripts, and the syllables reproduced are those in the Latin script at the top? If so, then any result that meets your vague criteria will be completely arbitrary, and likely not significantly different in appearance from either an abugida built from IPA or the 'standard' Latin transcription at the top of your image - except that it won't be any more readable to me than text written with the Samarkan font is to someone who only reads Devanagari.

Comment: The image is from Wikipedia and all phrases are transliterations of each other. I just added the parts in red. The glyph shapes are not derived arbitrarily from their ancestors and neither should be those of the conscript.

Comment: http://www.themicrofoundry.com/other/thai.gif is close to what I mean, using Thai

Comment: [yikes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anglocentrism)

Comment: I have seen examples of a Thai typeface with a very roman look (more so than @Crissov's last example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
[Franabugida](http://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/franabugida.htm) by [François Boullion](http://les-delires-d-uff.eklablog.com/franabugida-c19160771), though developed for writing French, is a faux roman script with abugida features that fulfills the criteria pretty well, although some of the resulting shapes look quite foreign.

[image]
[Akkhara Muni](http://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/akkharamuni.htm) by [Ian James](http://www.skyknowledge.com/akkharamuni.htm) comes close to being a roman-looking script with Brahmic abugida structure, although it lacks complex ligatures and (non-inherent) vowels are not diacritic-like.

[image]
The historic (but unused) [Ariyaka](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/ariyaka.php) [script](http://www.skyknowledge.com/ariyaka.htm) for writing Pali from 19th-century Siam/Thailand is also obviously inspired by Latin and Greek letter forms and the Brahmic system.

[image]
[BLUIS](http://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/bluis.htm) by Punya Pranava Pasumarty does not meet the criteria, but due to its design, it could be used as a base: One would just need to make the letter forms more roman-looking.

Comment: If this is what you're after, then my original question was pretty might right, even though you said it wasn't? "Latin consonants used as an abugida with diacritics instead of the Latin vowels"

Comment: Except that the Latin letters should not be used for their usual phonological value, but for visual similarity to letters of existing Brahmic scripts.

Answer (score 5):

[image: bgd]

Next project: Pama-Nyungan inspired vocabulary, but using English words

Comment: Simultaneously beautiful and horrific!

Comment: I see how my question could be misunderstood in this way. I’m looking for a script whose looks fit well with the Roman script, not for an abugida build with IPA symbols.

Comment: @Crissov: IPA *is* the Latin script (or a specialised adaptation of it, anyway). Does replacing as4s4hetic's glyphs with plain alphabetic letters (like **a** for **æ**) meet your expectations?